# In Ruby when I pass a file to a variable

Tags: ruby

What I am trying to do :

```
date = `date +%Y%m%d`
Path = "/home/sajeesh/jam_#{date}"

if File.file?(Path)

      watch_for(Path, /FATAL/)

    else 

      exit 1
end
```

So when I do the condition; instead of jam_20170508 its taking jam_#{date} and its exiting; any possible workaround for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: It is not necessary in Ruby to shell out to the `date` command line utility. Look at Ruby's documentation for core `Time` class e.g. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html - you can use this to generate the same string format.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Neil; Will try to use that method.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be new line in `Path`.

Try using

```
Path = "/home/sajeesh/jam_#{date}".strip
```

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan you never accept the answers provided to your questions. Please, make sure to go over your questions and select and accept the one answer per question, that solves it best (given that there are such answers).